# Multiple Count based on value MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table that have the following columns and sample data.

(this data is output of a query so i have to use that query in FROM () statement)

```
Type|  Time              | Count
--------------------------------
1   |2013-05-09 12:00:00 | 71
2   |2013-05-09 12:00:00 | 48
3   |2013-05-09 12:00:00 | 10
3   |2013-05-09 13:00:00 | 4
2   |2013-05-16 13:00:00 | 30
1   |2013-05-16 13:00:00 | 31
1   |2013-05-16 14:00:00 | 4
3   |2013-05-16 14:00:00 | 5
```

I need to group data based on time so my output should look like this

```
AlarmType1 | AlarmType2 |AlarmType3| AlarmTime
--------------------------------
71         | 48         | 10       | 2013-05-09 12:00:00
31         | 30         | 4        | 2013-05-09 13:00:00
4          | 0          | 5        | 2013-05-09 14:00:00
```

i have tried this query

```
SELECT
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '1',1,0)) as  AlarmType1,
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '2',1,0)) as  AlarmType2,
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '3',1,0)) as  AlarmType3,
AlarmHour
FROM 'Table1'
GROUP BY Time
```

but this did not work, as i am missing Count in my Query, have to adjust Count im my Query

Comment: i found one mistake that i am not using my Count in my query. but is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need SUM(Count), not SUM(1):

```
SELECT
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '1',Count,0)) as  AlarmType1,
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '2',Count,0)) as  AlarmType2,
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '3',Count,0)) as  AlarmType3,
AlarmHour
FROM 'Table1'
GROUP BY Time
```

Comment: yes, Count was missing and adjusted, this worked. i am noob to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Your `table1` is your subquery right? Well it has to have its alias so it will be something like that

```
SELECT
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '1',1,0)) as  AlarmType1,
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '2',1,0)) as  AlarmType2,
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '3',1,0)) as  AlarmType3,
AlarmHour
FROM (subquery giving table1) as subTable
GROUP BY subtable.Time
```

**EDIT:**
As for summing, why dont you just use multiple `group by`? EG. `GROUP BY Type, Time` and show type for every group and type `SELECT Type,Time,Sum(Count) ...`?

OK I get it now what are you trying to achieve. If you want to "add columns" you will have to use `JOINS`. So create single query for every column you need (every AlarmType count) and join them on commond value whitch is Time of alarm.

Comment: i have tried this approach yesterday, this only shows if the id for a particular date exists or not, i mean just 1 and 0, instead of the count of the alarm, i figured out i have not used my count in my query, so have to adjust the count in the query

Comment: I didn't analized your query, just answered how to handle error reported by you.

Comment: if i simply group by Time, ID info will be lost, i don't know much about mysql, so i may be wrong in understating your edit.

Comment: i have an option to filter my record in my [tag:C#] application, but it would be better if i get the data in required format

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "info will be lost"?

Comment: instead of retrieving ` 71 | 48 | 10 ` it gives me the sum ie `133`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(IF (AlarmType = '1',1,0)) as  AlarmType1,
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '2',1,0)) as  AlarmType2,
SUM(IF (AlarmType = '3',1,0)) as  AlarmType3,
AlarmHour
FROM (your query) as t group by t.Time
```